# Use rayCast() in none-game scripts?

Tags: scripting

I want to make a scripts that adapts meshes and I need to cast rays for this.
But the rayCast() function is part of the game engine and it seems these functions can not be used by the standard scripting.
IS there a way I can use the rayCast() function?

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by "adapting meshes". Perhaps you can add a picture or explain it more?

Comment: Blender can cast rays outside of the game engine, best ask a more specific question.